# Error when fitting LSTM on Time Series Data

Tags: r, keras, time-series, lstm

I have daily time series data of 14 features. I am interested in predicting a one-step ahead forecast for feature 1 (binary) using all features 1 to 14. In order to do so I implement a LSTM model in R using Keras.

To work with the LSTM layer I convert my train and validation data matrix in a 3D array with dimension:

```
> dim(train_x)
[1] 1093    1   14

> dim(valid_x)
[1] 366   1  14
```

`train_y` is a 1D vector with length 1093. Also, `train_y` equals the first input feature of `train_x` but it is lagged forward by 1 timestep (one-step ahead forecast).

After running the following code:

```
model <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
  layer_lstm(units = 32, input_shape = list(dim(train_x)[[2]], dim(train_x)[[3]])) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "sigmoid")

model %>% compile(
  optimizer = "rmsprop",
  loss = "binary_crossentropy",
  metrics = c("accuracy")
)

history <- model %>% fit(
  x = train_x,
  y = train_y,
  steps_per_epoch = 500,
  epochs = 20,
  validation_data = list(valid_x, valid_y),
  shuffle=FALSE
)
```

the network trains successfully until the first epoch is almost over and then returns the following error:

```
...
453/500 [==========================>...] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4137 - acc: 0.8219
461/500 [==========================>...] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4125 - acc: 0.8227
469/500 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4113 - acc: 0.8236
477/500 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4101 - acc: 0.8244
485/500 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4089 - acc: 0.8252
493/500 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4077 - acc: 0.8260
 Show Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Do you have any ideas what is going on? I tried to google the error but I could not figure out how to fix it in my specific case.

Help is much appreciated :)

*Edit: If it helps, I tried to follow the procedure on  https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/ but the code is written in Python, which means I am not sure if I did everything correct using R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually solved the problem. The issue occurred because I missed the `validation_steps` argument in `fit()`. It has to be set to the number of samples (batch size) used for validation.